# Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be independat RVs with PDF $2t$ on $[0,1]$, and $0$ else. $W=max(X,Y,Z)$. What is the expected value of $W$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification

> Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be independent RVs with PDF $2t$ on $[0,1]$, and $0$ else. $W=max(X,Y,Z)$. What is the expected value of W?

So first off we need to find $F_W(t)$, and derive it to find $f_W(t)$, and then use that to find E(Z).

$Pr(W\le w)=Pr(max(X,Y,Z) \lt w)=Pr(X\lt w)Pr(Y\lt w)Pr(Z\lt w)=$

$$F_W(t)=\int_0^t (2t')^3dt'=2t'^4|^w_0=2t^4$$

Differentiating we get

$$f_W(t)=8t^3$$

Now finding E(W):

$$\int_0^1 t*8t^3dt=\frac85$$

Now the answer is wrong, and I'm wondering during which step the mistake occured.

Comment: What do mean when you say the pdf is $2t$? What is $t$?

Comment: You have used the density for $P(X \le w)$ etc. when you should have used the cumulative distribution function

Comment: "So first off we need to find FW(t), and derive it to find fW(t), and then use that to find E(Z)" Actually we do not need to do that. Instead, $W\geqslant0$ almost surely hence $$E(W)=\int_0^{\infty}P(W\geqslant w))dw,$$(a formula worth remembering), secondly, $P(W\geqslant w)=0$ if $w>1$ and $W$ is a maximum of independent random variables hence, for every $w$ in $(0,1)$, $$P(W\leqslant w)=P(X\leqslant w)P(Y\leqslant w)P(Z\leqslant w)=P(X\leqslant w)^3,$$ third, the CDF is the integral of the PDF hence $$P(X\leqslant w)=w^2.$$ Putting these together yields $$E(W)=\int_0^1(1-w^6)dw=\frac67.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cumulative probability distribution $G$ of each of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ is given by $G(t)=t^2$ and the probability density function $g$ is given by $g(t)=2t$.

Thus the cumulative distribution $F$ of $W$ is given by

$$F(t)=Pr(X\leq t)Pr(Y\leq t)Pr(Z\leq t)=[G(t)]^3=(t^2)^3=t^6$$

The probability density function, $f$ is given by $f(t)=6t^5$.

Thus the expected value of $W$ is

$$E[W]=\int_0^1tf(t)dt=\int_0^16t^6dt=\left[\frac{6t^7}{7}\right]_0^1=\frac{6}{7}.$$

---

Your answer is wrong because you calculated the cumulative distribution $F$ of $W$ using

$$F(t)=\int_0^t[g(x)]^3dx$$

instead of

$$F(t)=\left[\int_0^tg(x)dx\right]^3.$$

Comment: Thank for clearing it up !